# How to check if a ManyToManyField is subset of a queryset while filtering in Django

Tags: django, join, filter, many-to-many, django-queryset

```py
class OrganizationUser(models.Model):
    pass

class Feedback(models.Model):
  teams_shared_with = models.ManyToManyField('team.Team', related_name="feedback")

class Team(models.Model):
    leads = models.ManyToManyField('organizations.OrganizationUser', related_name='teams_lead_at')
    members = models.ManyToManyField('organizations.OrganizationUser', related_name='teams_member_at', blank=True)
```

I have the above models, all the fields were not shown. I want to filter those feedback which are shared in any team where I am a member or an admin.

I would like to do something like:

```py
Feedback.objects.filter(teams_shared_with is a subset of organization_user.teams_lead_at.all()|organization_user.teams_member_at.all())
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q

user1 = OrganizationUser.objects.first() #some organization user

Feedback.objects.filter(
    Q(teams_shared_with__leads=user1)
    |Q(teams_shared_with__members=user1)
)
```

Comment: teams_shared_with is also a ManyToManyField, will acessing leads and members through the field work?

Comment: Yes, try it....

Comment: why should I need to call ``.distinct()``? Suppose ``Q(teams_shared_with__members = users)`` is ``True`` for a feedback. The feedback would be present in the filtered queryset. But why would the feedback appear multiple times, if there is no duplicate of the feedback in the original queryset?

Answer (score 1):

There is chance of duplication of Feedback use distinct() to avoid that

```
from django.db.models import Q

users = OrganizationUser.objects.all()

Feedback.objects.filter(
    Q(teams_shared_with__leads = users)
    |Q(teams_shared_with__members = users)
).distinct()
```

Comment: You're right. I forgot about that.

Comment: why should I need to call ```.distinct()```?
Suppose ``Q(teams_shared_with__members = users)`` is True for a feedback. The feedback would be present in the filtered queryset. But why would the feedback appear multiple times, if there is no duplicate of the feedback in the original queryset? @ShiBil PK @lucutzu33